# Developing an understanding of capacitor

Tags: capacitor, short-circuit

I want to develop a better understanding of capacitors, thought about several problems and would like to check with more experienced, if my current understanding is correct and enough for solving these problems.

Let's be given a very simple circuit with a voltage source, a capacitor and an opened switch. 
Closing the switch makes the capacitor become charged at one plate with electrons, building up an electric field between the plates and making the electrons of the other plate be repelled and thus creating another flow of electrons in the circuit. 
First problem: What happens, if the switch is opened abruptly. 
I guess, the electric field between the plates immediately collapses and the electrons of the first plate, try "to escape" (the capacitor can no longer store the energy), creating a voltage spike and the electrons look for a voltage sink. (Maybe they will try to move back to the voltage source or to the 2th plate)

Second problem: Now there is also a resistance bypass over the capacitor. I consider the capacitor to be of "infinite" resistance thus not storing any energy at all. 
Switching off or on doesn't do much and nothing fancy can happen.

Third problem: The bypass is only activated, if the switch to the capacitor is opened. If the switch is opened, the electrons would create a very strong electrical current through the capacitor. (If the capacitor only has a considerable low resistance, it should become extremely hot. Not what, what happens, if the resistor has resistance 0.

Fourth problem instead of an resistance a coil is used. I would expect the coil to produce a very strong magnetic field, however for just a short time. Is there actually formula for computing how long the magnetic field can be kept alive, if the switch is abruptly opened? I could even imagine that field instantly comes into existence and collapses.

At the moment these are all questions I have. I would be very happy, if someone has the time to reply and can offer some constructive critique. As always thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you a basic book on physics of electricity...

Comment: First problem: no, no voltage spike. Switch opens abruptly, current stops abruptly, and capacitor field stays constant. Don't really understand the rest of the problems. You should probably draw a schematic to make it more clear. But it sounds like you are pretty confused.

Comment: *"Let's be given a very simple circuit"* Then show us the schematic. You will not get (m)any answers without one. This is a broad question which can be at least partly answered if you took the trouble to read about basic electronics. You make some assumptions because you lack some basic knowledge that is readily available if you just go look for it and absorb it. It you want to learn about electronics, there is no other way. We all had to learn that way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is making assertions in the question that are false rendering the question, in my opinion flawed. 2nd problem is the 2nd problem in the question being unfathomable. 3rd problem stated in the question is largely untrue. It's a mess. Don't make assertions, ask questions.

Comment: Please read the guidelines on asking questions http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  Thanks. Also poke around the help center for help on appropriate topics.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens, if the switch is opened abruptly. I guess, the electric field between the plates immediately collapses and the electrons of the first plate, try "to escape"

This is incorrect. Once you open the switch, the charge on the capacitor has no way to escape. The E fields stays constant and the capacitor stores its energy until some path is provided for charge to escape it.

(In reality, there is a leakage path through the capacitor itself, and the charge slowly leak through this, discharging the capacitor, but this is likely to take minutes or hours to happen)

A key thing to remember is that energy can't be instantaneously transferred in or out of the capacitor. Because this would require an infinite current to be applied. This means the capacitor voltage can't change instantaneously either.

> I consider the capacitor to be of "infinite" resistance thus not storing any energy at all.

This doesn't make any sense. An ideal capacitor has infinite resistance and it still stores energy proportional to the square of the voltage across it.

> instead of an resistance a coil is used. I would expect the coil to produce a very strong magnetic field, however for just a short time.

If you put an inductor and a capacitor in parallel (or in series) you will create a resonant circuit. The behavior is somewhat more complicated than just a field being created and then decaying away. Rather, you will see an oscillation as energy is transferred back and forth between the inductor and the capacitor.

Comment: I think he is confused about ESR vs. plate to plate resistance.  A capacitor with infinite ESR would indeed store no energy.  It might we worth editing your answer (which is otherwise great by the way) to talk about how leakage current and that resistance is measured from one plate to the other plate, and is NOT the resistance of current/electrons flowing onto or off of the plates.  That is ESR, which is indeed typically very low.  Also, he says the capacitor would get very hot, which is also incorrect.  Temperature rise has to do with joules, not current.  1000A across 10mΩ for 1µs is 10mJ.

Comment: @metacollin, I think I captured the main point when I said "this doesn't make any sense". OP needs to study (or ask more questions about) the basics to learn enough of our (EE's) language to be able to ask a clear question. If we tried to explain everything OP doesn't understand at this point we'd have to write a few books. (But also it would be okay if you post another answer that clears up more points that I didn't cover)